# How to put a different UITableView in each UICollectionView Cell with unique datasource?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm tagging 5 tableViews (each with a unique data source) and placing them inside an equal number of UICollectionCells which are added to a UICollectionView.

The goal is to have the user swipe horizontally and show each tableView with a unique set of data. The following code works fine but the data starts repeating after the third swipe.

It looks like each tableView is tagged properly in `cellForItemAt` and I can see them show up in `cellForRowAt` (where a unique data source is assigned) until the fourth tableView.

What's interesting is that if I swipe up the cells that were pushed off the screen appear with the right data. Does the tableView need to be reloaded? Or is it the collectionView?

What would cause only the first three tableViews to work properly? I'm new to swift so I'm hoping this is something simple.

```
import UIKit

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let reuseIdentifier1 = "reuseIdentifier1"

    var tableView: UITableView = UITableView()

    var array0 = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
    var array1 = ["1", "1", "1", "1", "1"]
    var array2 = ["2", "2", "2", "2", "2"]
    var array3 = ["3", "3", "3", "3", "3"]
    var array4 = ["4", "4", "4", "4", "4"]

    override init(frame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: frame)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier1)
        setupTableView()

    }

    func setupTableView() {

        addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true
        tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}

extension CollectionViewCell: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier1, for: indexPath)

        // CHANGE TABLE DATA DEPENDING ON TAG
        if tableView.tag == 0 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = array0[indexPath.item]
        }
        if tableView.tag == 1 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = array1[indexPath.item]
        }
        if tableView.tag == 2 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = array2[indexPath.item]
        }
        if tableView.tag == 3 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = array3[indexPath.item]
        }
        if tableView.tag == 4 {
            cell.textLabel?.text = array4[indexPath.item]
        }

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let reuseIdentifier2 = "cell"

    let theCollectionView:UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init())
    let theCollectionViewLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.init()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        theCollectionView.frame = .zero
        theCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        theCollectionView.dataSource = self
        theCollectionView.delegate = self
        theCollectionViewLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        theCollectionViewLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
        theCollectionViewLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
        theCollectionViewLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        theCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = theCollectionViewLayout

        theCollectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        theCollectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier2)
        theCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        view.addSubview(theCollectionView)

        theCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        theCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        theCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        theCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    }

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier2, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        // TAG THE TABLEVIEWS HERE
        cell.tableView.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: theCollectionView.frame.width, height: theCollectionView.frame.height)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are assuming, when you say `if tableView.tag ==` in the table view's `cellForRowAt`, that this table view's tag has already been changed in the collection view's `cellForItemAt`. But you do not *know* that this is the order in which things happen, so that's a risky assumption — and indeed, it apparently is not working.

You can easily confirm this with some breakpoints or logging to reveal the order in which things happen as you swipe.

Also, be warned that the table view from collection view item 0 might get reused in, say, item 3. But then you will need to *reload* the table view once it has its new tag, in order to make it take on its new cell value. Otherwise you'll just go on seeing the cell from item 0 (apparently exactly what is happening to you).

Comment: Yes, I think you're right about reloading. I played around with reloading the tableView and the collectionView but neither did much. But the fact that the correct cells appear if I swipe them off the screen tells me this is likely it.

Answer (score 1):

OK... this is it. I simply added the following line before `return cell` in `cellForItemAt`.

`cell.tableView.reloadData()`

It works!

Comment: Yes, that makes sense (and is what I was saying in the last paragraph of my answer).